# How to share a single styles.css file in a v13 nx and angular monorepo

Tags: angular, build, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I am upgrading an nx / angular monorepo to nx 13.10. I am wondering if it is possible to relocate the built `styles.1234etc.css` file to a directory `dist/styles`, which is what we had been doing in older versions.

We used to do this in `angular.json` `build.options` for each app:

```
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "./libs/assets/css/styles.scss",
                "bundleName": "../../styles/styles"
              }
            ]
```

... and this would result in `dist/styles/styles.1234etc.css`, instead of `dist/[appName]/styles.1234etc.css`. The location of styles object shown above is has now moved to `[appName]/project.json`. However, in newer versions of Angular, the `bundleName` path in that example is no longer a valid value for `bundlename`. It generates this error:
`An asset cannot be written to a location outside of the output path.`
So we have to do this instead:

```
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "./libs/assets/css/styles.scss",
                "bundleName": "styles"  <--filename, path no longer allowed
              }
            ]
```

Restated, we are now getting this build output (note location of styles in `dist/`):

```
nxng-example/
├── apps/
│   ├── qqq/
│   
├── libs/
│   ├── assets/
│       ├── styles/styles.css
│  
├── dist/
    ├── apps
        ├── qqq/
            ├── styles.12345etc.css  <-- move this...
            ├── index.html, and .js files
```

... and what I would prefer:

```
nxng-example/
├── apps/
│   ├── qqq/
│   
├── libs/
│   ├── assets/
│       ├── styles/styles.css
│  
├── dist/
    ├── apps
    │   ├── qqq/
    │       ├── index.html, and .js files
    │ 
    ├── styles.12345etc.css   <-- ...to here
```

This is not critical - not breaking - and I can live with it, and I could use a script to fix this after the build (probably will just accept the new way, though), but I am just wondering if there is an easy way to have `dist/styles/styles.1234etc.css`, that I have just overlooked?

I have a minimal monorepo for example code at https://github.com/srbStackblitz/nxng-example. Thanks.